# Visual Studio 2019 Crashes Without Error Message When Adding SqlDataSource to Gridview

Tags: visual-studio, crash

I'm using latest update and I don't have any plugins. Recently I had no problem with adding datasource to gridview but today when I click "test connection" or "ok" buttons, Visual Studio closes itself without showing any error messages. I tried to do same process in different project but the result was same. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: have you checked your event logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using default Access database (.accdb) format which uses Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0. So I saved my database as Access 2002-2003 (.mdb) format and changed the connection strings with Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0 in my project. Looks like works fine for now.

Also, Check your database path if it consists of any non-English letters.

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>